# “merge” two readers into one writer with special condition

Tags: java, merge, bufferedreader, filereader

I need to implement the method
public static void filter(Reader mails, Reader groups, Writer users) in such a way that it would combine two pieces of data frow readers into one writer.

The file for mails:

```
Login;Email
#ivanovjti;ivanov@mail.com
petrovjti;petrov@google.com
obamajti;obama@yahoo.com
```

and the file for groups:

```
Login;Group
ivanovjti;Java1
petrovjti;Java2
obamajti;Java1
```

result of merging should look like this:

```
Login;Email;Group
#ivanovjti;ivanov@mail.com;Java1
petrovjti;petrov@google.com;Java2
obamajti;obama@yahoo.com;Java1
```

My code:

```
package homework_4;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void filter(Reader mails, Reader groups, Writer users) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader brm = new BufferedReader(mails);
        BufferedReader brg = new BufferedReader(groups);
        BufferedWriter bru = new BufferedWriter(users);

        String m = brm.readLine();
        String g = brg.readLine();

        while (m != null && g != null) {
            bru.write(m + ";" + g.split(";")[1] + "\n");
            m = brm.readLine();
            g = brg.readLine();
        }
        bru.flush();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

            FileReader frm = new FileReader("homework_4_1.txt");
            FileReader frg = new FileReader("homework_4_2.txt");
            FileWriter fwu = new FileWriter("homework_4_3.txt");

            filter(frm, frg, fwu);

            frm.close();
            frg.close();
            fwu.close();

    }

}
```

But i have one condition. If file mails, or file groups contains symbol "#", the result of merging should look like this:

```
Login;Email;Group
petrovjti;petrov@google.com;Java2
obamajti;obama@yahoo.com;Java1
```

I don't know how to make this. Which method checks this special symbol ?

Comment: `"homework_4_1.txt"` `"homework_4_2.txt"` `"homework_4_3.txt"`--Hmm...

Comment: homework_4_1 contains mail.
homework_4_2 contains groups.
homework_4_3 contains users.

Comment: Just observe the Strings that you just read, and if one of them starts with a `#`, continue with next read.

Comment: ok. but how do this ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `String`s variables containing each line of the files. As I can see in your examples, **what you need is to ignore lines containing `#` symbol**. (correctme if I'm wrong).

- To check if `String` contains another `String` use [`String::contains("#")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).
- To check if a `String` startsWith another `String` use 
  [`String::startsWith(prefix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)):

```
String m = brm.readLine();   
String g = brg.readLine();

while (m != null && g != null) {
    // check if contains # and write otherwise
    if(!m.contains("#") && !g.contains("#")) {
        bru.write(m + ";" + g.split(";")[1] + "\n");
    }
    m = brm.readLine();
    g = brg.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I do not think it's so easy

Comment: you where already there, please save the String API links I gave, [Java official documentation is great](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/index.html). It will help you in the future, is quite easy to use and really descriptive :)

Comment: @PidunaV.A. also don't care about rude users, StackOverflow is a bit like a jungle at the begining... ;)